# How to set up libzmq plaintext auth

Tags: zeromq

I want to setup libzmq plaintext authentication for my pub server. How can I do that??

The official doc is too simple. http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-plain. I set ZMQ_PLAIN_SERVER = 1, But I don't know how to set username and password to the socket.

In Java, I can use

```
public ZAuth configurePlain(String domain, String filename)
```

To specify an auth file, then I put usernames and passwords in it like the following:

```
username1=password1 
username2=password2 
...
```

I found czmq has a similar operation http://czmq.zeromq.org/czmq4-0:zauth which I failed to see
the equivalent in libzmq.

Comment: Well, it's not too simple, it says "server shall set the ZMQ_PLAIN_SERVER option" and "See also zmq_setsockopt". As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I said I've set ZMQ_PLAIN_SERVER = 1 but I don't know how to add usernames/passwords to the server. zmq_setsockopt doc doesn't help.

Comment: I see, sorry. To be honest, I haven't experimented with it myself yet, so I'm just guessing. Looking at https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/24, it have a feeling that there is nothing built-in that does this. The only thing is that the client sends credentials on connect, but those take the form of a "normal" message exchange. That however doesn't explain why you would have to set a flag for the server side as well. Sorry, I effectively can't help you, the only suggestion I have is to read existing sourcecode, maybe that gives you the missing hint. Good luck!

Comment: Many high-level wrappers (e.g. czmq) have clear interfaces of plaintext auth. It's a pity libzmq itself doesn't have a clear explanation of that, maybe because they encourage people to use high-level wrappers rather than libzmq? I'm using rust libzmq binding, using high-level wrappers is not an option for me. So yes, perhaps reading the source code is the only way. Anyway, thank you again for your help. :)